# Samsung Data Migration software isn't working

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, migration

I just bought a Samsung 840 Series SSD.
I am in trying to migrate my data from my current laptop's HDD to the SSD.
I am using the Samsung Data Migration Software, however it is not working? I am not sure why?
It is stucked at 0% forever.

I am only using up 100GB of my current drive. My SSD has a 250GB capacity.
I have only 1 drive and I am running it while doing the migration. The software doesn't ask me to restart or anything? I find it weird as in, how can you do a data migration when you are using the drive?

Thanks,
Venn.

Answer (score 4):

Those tools are often times junk, a better solution would be to use something like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to accomplish this.

The way it works is you would download the `.iso`, burn it to a disc (or USB) and boot from that.  Then, no hard drives are directly mounted and then it'll walk you through.

Another option would be to boot any [Linux Live Disc](http://www.livecdlist.com/) and do a bit-by-bit clone.  If you do it this way, I would just default to Ubuntu since it's common and well supported by the community.

The command you would use is `dd if=/dev/sd[x] of=/dev/sd[y]`  **[x] would be replaced with the FROM drive, [y] would be replaced with the TO.** If you approach it this way, ask for help and do more research - as you could kill your old hard drive's data if you mess up.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent F&F (fruitless & frustrating!) hours with Migration Wizard v3.1 taking me in circles - "Do you want to upgrade to latest version v2.5.1?" It apparently did NOT upgrade. After supposedly cloning my new Samsung laptop's HDD it the system did not recognize the new SSD at all.

After some difficulty I located a Samsung download page for Magician 4.0 AND Migration Wizard v2.5.1 (http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html).  After unzipping the package I tried the cloning operation again.  This time it worked like a charm! I just now spent another 15 minutes swapping out the drives and tested - my new laptop now boots from a cold (off overnight) start to fully operational in 15-20 seconds! I am delighted with what I've seen thus far, and am thinking that I should have gone for a larger SSD!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using *[Seagate Disc Wizard](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/discwizard/)* for quite some time and I absolutely love it. It's really good and is freeware.

Today after giving up on *Samsung Data Migration* software I've successfully used it yet again to clone all three partitions (including the primary bootable one) of my laptop's HDD to a brand new Samsung 840 Series SSD drive.

Comment: You need to own a seagate product to use disc wizard, so save your self the trouble of downloading it.

Comment: @william - mechanically or license-wise?